# Parsing large XML file and inserting the data to MongoDB in the fastest way

Tags: python, mongodb, xml-parsing, in-memory

I have 5.5 GB XML file needs to be parsed and insert into MongoDB. My XML will have different classes / group. sample group:

```xml
<parent class="class1">
    <p key="value"/>        
</parent>
<parent class="class2">
    <p key="value"/>
    <p key1="value1"/>
    <p key2="value2"/>
</parent>
```

The classes are located all over the file (not sequential or grouped). Each group should be inserted into a separate Mongo Collection.

Solution:

1. I used `lxml` library from python to parse the XML file, this library is a memory-efficient.
2. I loop through the entire ~5GB file and grouping the unique class elements
3. The consolidated data per class is stored in a separate collection in MongoDB

The above process is taking approximately 1.5 hours. Parsing: ~1 hour and 23 mins. Mongo insertion: ~7 mins

I want each class to have a unique collection in MongoDB, the data i want is the parent attributes (e.g. class='class1') + the children elements (p) in one document for each group (parent+child).

Is there any in-memory libraries that I can use to speed up the overall processing time?

Comment: You should include how much time each of the steps is taking

Comment: There seems to be information needed for troubleshooting missing from the question. To the point of the comment above, is it the last step that's taking the most time? If so, how many documents in the database does this process create and how are they being inserted (eg one at a time or in bulk)?

Comment: Please give a little more of the input XML and what you want to see inserted into mongodb as a document.